# Why can't an $\omega$-stable theory have finitely many countable models?

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

This is a "well-known fact," but I'm at a loss to finding a proof.  I could swear I've read it somewhere, but checking the handful of places I'm used to checking doesn't help.  Google gives nothing, so let's have a proof here!

**Theorem:** Suppose $T$ is a (countable complete) $\omega$-stable theory.  Then $T$ is either $\aleph_0$-categorical or $T$ has infinitely many countable models.

Does anyone know a proof?

Answer (score 7):

I won't give a proof, but I will give some historical background and references.

Let $I(T,\kappa)$ be the number of isomorphism types of models of $T$ of cardinality $\kappa$. A countable complete theory $T$ with $1<I(T,\aleph_0)<\aleph_0$ is called an *Ehrenfeucht theory*.

**Theorem (Baldwin-Lachlan, 1971):** No Ehrenfeucht theory is uncountably categorical.

Indeed, the Baldwin-Lachlan analysis shows that models of an uncountably categorical theory are determined up to isomorphism by the dimension of a strongly minimal set, and the possible dimensions for a countable model are upwards-closed in $\{0,1,2,\dots,\aleph_0\}$.

Now uncountably categorical theories are $\omega$-stable, and $\omega$-stable theories are superstable. Just two years later, Lachlan pushed the lower bound on the complexity of Ehrenfeucht theories all the way to superstability:

**Theorem (Lachlan, 1973):** No Ehrenfeucht theory is superstable.

I don't know of any proof in the $\omega$-stable case which is easier than the general superstable case, but I would be very interested to see one!

You can find Lachlan's proof in his paper *On the number of countable models of a countable superstable theory* (if you can find the paper - I couldn't!), but it's apparently quite complicated. The proof was substantially simplified by Lascar in his important 1976 paper *Ranks and definability in superstable theories*, as an application of his newly-minted $U$-rank.

Since then, several other proofs have been given. If you want to read a proof in a textbook, Lachlan's theorem is the very last theorem in Pillay's little book Introduction to Stability Theory, and it appears as Theorem 5.6.2 in Buechler's *Essential Stability Theory*.

Lachlan's theorem was generalized by Kim:

**Theorem (Kim, 1999):** No Ehrenfeucht theory is supersimple.

Kim's paper *On the number of countable models of a countable supersimple theory* is very short and self-contained (modulo the basic properties of forking in simple theories), so it might actually be the most direct place to read the proof, even for the $\omega$-stable case!

An important question is whether we can remove the "super":

**Lachlan's Problem:** Is there a stable Ehrenfeucht theory?

Hrushovski addressed this problem in his thesis, where he showed that no Ehrenfeucht theory is stable and "finitely based".

In 2001, Sudoplatov announced a positive solution to Lachlan's Problem, which he subsequently laid out in his book *The Lachlan Problem*. I have not read the book (though I am interested in reading it at some point!).

You can find a very complete history of Ehrenfeucht theories (and information about the proposed solution to Lachlan's problem) starting on p. 9 of [these slides](http://www.math.nsc.ru/~sudoplatov/papers/prezKaraganda2012Sudoplatov.pdf) by Sudoplatov.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I believe the proof in Buechler was the one I was thinking of, so thanks for finding the reference, too. Excellent!